# Empty nodes when creating a SOM in R

Tags: r, unsupervised-learning, som, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to create a SOM map based on records with different discrete classifications (tags) like the example below

```
Record                   Tag1       Tag2       Tag3      Tag4
3555                        1          0          0         0
6447                        1          0          0         0
5523                        1          0          1         0
7550                        1          0          1         0
6330                        1          0          1         0 
2451                        1          0          0         0
4308                        1          0          1         0
8917                        0          0          0         0
4780                        1          0          1         0
6802                        1          0          1         0
2021                        1          0          0         0
5792                        1          0          1         0
5475                        1          0          1         0 
4198                        1          0          0         0
223                         1          0          1         0
4811                        1          0          1         0
678                         1          0          1         0
```

The problem I am facing is that there are many empty nodes in the SOM. From what I have read, each node should have 5-10 records but still, this is not working.

[image]

Could it be that all observations are very different from one another?